# Can someone explain the behavior of the output while returning an array from function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

**Code:**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int * arrayReturn();

int main(){
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout<<"Value at "<<i<<": "<<arrayReturn()[i]<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int * arrayReturn(){
    static int arr[] = {10,20,30,40};
    
    return arr;
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Question:**
Can anyone please comment on the output of the code? Why value at 4th position is 4659536 and -1 at 8th & 9th place instead of 0?

**Note:** Please avoid suggestions to correct the code(it's just a test code), only provide a reason for the output.

Comment: Those are just some garbage values as you're going out of bounds.

Comment: What do you think about printing ten elements from an array that only have four? That is an Undefined Behavior, ie garbage.

Comment: `ArrayReturn()` returns a pointer to the first element of an array that has exactly four elements.   It doesn't actually return an array.   Using the returned pointer `main()` attempts to print ten elements of that array which is known to only have four elements.   The behaviour is therefore undefined.   Printing garbage values is a common symptom of undefined behaviour.  In your case, the three zero values you get are also just happenstance.

Comment: @Peter Thanks. A follow-up question. Every time I execute the program, it should throw a different garbage value, but I get constant value here. Why?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: There is no requirement that a different "garbage value" should be output.   The behaviour is undefined.   That means the standard says nothing about what should happen.   The standard doesn't require garbage values at all, it doesn't require different garbage values every time, it doesn't require the same garbage value every time, it doesn't require reformatting your hard drive.  But all of those things can potentially occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled and executed your code.

This is the output:

```
$ ./sample.o 
Value at 0: 10
Value at 1: 20
Value at 2: 30
Value at 3: 40
Value at 4: -346453624
Value at 5: 32646
Value at 6: -346453584
Value at 7: 32646
Value at 8: 6
Value at 9: 0
```

Please note the values from index 4 onward. **They are garbage.**

As the original array contains only 4 elements, you can't really go beyond the 4th element (3rd index) without entering the **Undefined Behaviour** territory.

Every time you execute the code, you might get different values.

Comment: Yes. it can't go beyond the bounds. Are you getting the same garbage value for every run?

Comment: One never knows what values they will get for garbage. The values might be same for all the runs; or they might be different. Getting same or different values doesn't mean anything. One can never rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

The input array has been initialized with four values only: 10, 20, 30, 40. The 'for' loop iterates 10 times. In C++, the index operator will happily return the values at whatever location it finds, but in this case only the first four values are valid; all the following values are invalid.